# Finding $x$, $y$ that minimize $(\frac{\sqrt3\sin y}{\sqrt2\sin(x+y)}+1)(\frac{\sqrt2\sin x}{3\sin y}+1)^2(\frac{\sin(x+y)}{7\sqrt3\sin x}+1)^4$

Tags: functions, trigonometry

This problem was given in 2018 in the entrance exams for MSU(8th problem). The only information online about the exam is its answers and is supposedly aimed at **highschool** students. I am in a maths-oriented high school so we are studying what we would in the 1st year in uni. The problem is:

> Find all pairs of $x,y \in (0;\frac{\pi}{2}) $ where $f(x,y) = f_{min}$. (When is this equal to its minimum value)
>
> $$ f(x,y) =   \left(\frac{\sqrt3\sin y} {\sqrt2\sin(x+y)} + 1\right)\left(\frac{\sqrt2\sin x}{3\sin y} + 1\right)^2\left( \frac{\sin(x+y)}{7\sqrt3\sin x} + 1\right)^4  $$

I only want a starting point, how do I approach this? Derivatives? Or do the (...)^4 ?

Comment: I should note that my maths teacher couldn't help me.

Comment: maybe $a,b,c=\sin(x),\sin(y),\sin(x+y)$ and [Lagrange multipliers](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimize+%28sqrt%283%29*b%2F%28sqrt%282%29*c%29%2B1%29*%28sqrt%282%29*a%2F%283*b%29%2B1%29%5E2*%28c%2F%287*sqrt%283%29*a%29%2B1%29%5E4+when+0%3Ca%3C1%2C0%3Cb%3C1%2Cc%3Dsqrt%281-a%5E2%29*b%2Bsqrt%281-b%5E2%29*a)?

Comment: Mathematica gives (after *long* thought) $(x,y)\approx (0.494021, 1.42152)$. No symbolic answer given. Hard to believe this is really a high school level problem.

Comment: Could you deliver a link to the answer?

Comment: Problems and their solutions(in Russian)
http://cpk.msu.ru/files/2018/tasks/math_solutions.pdf

Comment: an application of Holder's inequality is staring right at you. I am not sure if the equality condition from Holder would give the right answer though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think maybe the question is poorly worded. It says "find all pairs" but provably finding all solutions to the stationary point equations is tedious (even a CAS struggles). Allow me to reword the question:

Find the *unique* stationary point of the function $f(x, y)$ in the given interval.

What difference does that change in wording make? It means that you don't need to directly find all solutions and can just guess at solutions until you find one that works. Bear that in mind and I will now hint but not explicitly give the solution.

The function you want to find the stationary point of is of the form $f(x, y) = a(x, y)b(x, y)^2c(x, y)^4$ so using $f_x$ for $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ we have
$$
f_x = a_x b^2 c^4 + 2 b_x a b c^4 + 4 c_x a b^2 c^3
$$
but the key is we don't have to calculate this whole expression explicitly. Rather we recognise that it is zero if each term has a zero factor. The same goes for $f_y$.

Now the big hint: if you calculate $a_x$ etc what you will see is that the terms in $f_x$ and $f_y$ have some common factors. We just need to find $x$ and $y$ to make those common factors zero and then we have found a stationary point of $f$.

Following the above I find the same solution as in Claude Leibovici's answer.

Comment: It turns out this is much more Calculus than I should know but I read for a while more Calc and hope to finish it. I doubt myself though

Answer (score 1):

As @rogerl commented, it is *"hard to believe this is really a high school level problem".*

Running a CAS, what it obtained is, for the minimum,
$$x=0.61547971 \qquad y=0.95531662 \qquad \implies f_{min}=6.06562081$$

Searching with inverse symbolic calculators, the closest I found is
$$x=\cos ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\right)\implies \sin(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$$
$$y=\sec ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{3}\right)\implies \sin(y)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}$$ which make $\sin(x+y)=1$ and $f_{min}=\frac{131072}{21609}$.

Comment: If the optimum can be written in a reasonably nice algebraic way, that makes me suspect, there might be a clever way of proving it, but I don't see a way to do it either.

Comment: Is there a rigorous way to show that $\sin(x+y)=1$?

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin. I just computed.

Comment: @quarague. I tried with algebra : it is pure nightmare even assming that $x+y=\frac \pi 2$.

Comment: Assuming $a=\sin(x),\sin(y)=\sqrt{1-a^2}$ and getting $f'(a)$ with `sympy` yields $\left(21a + \sqrt{3}\right)^3\left(\sqrt{2}a + 3\sqrt{1 - a^2}\right)\left(-\sqrt{6}a^2\left(1 - a^2\right)^{\frac72}\left(21a + \sqrt{3}\right)\left(\sqrt{2}a + 3\sqrt{1 - a^2}\right) + 2\sqrt{2}a\left(1 - a^2\right)^3\left(21a + \sqrt{3}\right)\left(\sqrt{6 - 6a^2} + 2\right) - 4\sqrt{3}\left(1 - a^2\right)^4\left(\sqrt{2}a + 3\sqrt{1 - a^2}\right)\left(\sqrt{6 - 6a^2} + 2\right)\right)/\left(3500658a^5\left(1 - a^2\right)^5\right)$ -- not so scary)

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin. I had this one. As you say, *"not so scary"*. Just do it ! Cheers :-)

Comment: [OK](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0%3D-%5Csqrt%7B6%7Da%5E2%281+-+a%5E2%29%5E%281%2F2%29%2821a+%2B+%5Csqrt%7B3%7D%29%28%5Csqrt%7B2%7Da+%2B+3%5Csqrt%7B1+-+a%5E2%7D%29+%2B+2%5Csqrt%7B2%7Da%2821a+%2B+%5Csqrt%7B3%7D%29%28%5Csqrt%7B6+-+6a%5E2%7D+%2B+2%29+-+4%5Csqrt%7B3%7D%281+-+a%5E2%29%28%5Csqrt%7B2%7Da+%2B+3%5Csqrt%7B1+-+a%5E2%7D%29%28%5Csqrt%7B6+-+6a%5E2%7D+%2B+2%29)

Comment: I checked on the answers and they are the following:

$ x = \arccos \frac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt3}$
$ y = \arccos \frac{1}{\sqrt3}$

Comment: I still don't have a clue how to get to that point however.

Comment: @Midaga. Me neither ! It is a very strange problem. Cheers :-)